# Alexandrov topology in terms of category theory

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

An [Alexandrov topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) is a topology in which an arbitrary intersection of open sets is open.  The wikipedia article has some characterizations in terms of category theory:

> - **Finite inclusion map**: The inclusion maps $f_i:X_i\to X$ of the finite subspaces of $X$ form a *final sink*.
> - **Finite generation**: $X$ is finitely generated i.e. it is in the *final hull* of the finite spaces.

What does *final sink* and *final hull* mean?  Can you suggest any references about this topic?

(And does the second bullet mean the final hull of its final subspaces, or the final hull of finite spaces in general, whatever final hull is supposed to mean?)

Comment: The first property simply says that every Alexandroff space is the filtered colimit of its finite subsets. I'm guessing that `final hull' in this case refers to the coreflective hull generated by the class of finite spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *sink* is an indexed set of morphisms that all share the same codomain (but the domain of each morphism may be different).

We call a sink in $\mathrm{Top}$ *final* if the shared codomain of the sink carries the finest topology (on the underlying set of the codomain) that makes all the morphisms of the sink continuous.

The source/sink terminology is usually associated with the work of Jiří Adámek [1]. Indeed, I suspect that he came up with these two characterizations of Alexandrov spaces.

Since you seek references, I'd suggest consulting Adámek's textbooks directly: the freely available [Abstract and Concrete Categories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/17/tr17abs.html), along with the higher-level [Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/locally-presentable-and-accessible-categories/94CB48295B6AF097FC232313A57BDE17#) should cover sources, sinks, their initiality/finality, as well as finite generation.

[1] But probably originates from a category theory textbook of Horst Herrlich and George E. Strecker, as pointed out by Tyrone in the comments.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the language of sources and sinks is due Herrlich and Strecker, and not Adámek (Herrlich and Strecker are the other two authors of **Abstract and Concrete Categories**). Indeed, the terminology appears in the 1979 book **Category Theory** by Herrlich and Strecker. Since the preface of the book contains an explanation for its appearance, I'd suggest that this book is where the terminology was formally introduced for the first time.

Comment: As for the term `finitely-generated space` as a characterisation of Alexandroff spaces, it appears already in Herrlich's 1969 paper [Limit-Operators and Topological Coreflections](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-146-00/S0002-9947-1969-0252473-2/S0002-9947-1969-0252473-2.pdf), where it is tossed around nonchalantly as if it were in standard usage at the time.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks so much for providing some much-needed historical context. I certainly didn't mean to make a historical claim that source/sink originates with Adámek, merely that it's associated with his work. That's definitely where I recognized it from (but I'm much more familiar with his work than the other authors). I do suspect (although I admittedly don't have much evidence to show) that the characterizations above, phrased in the particular language, are due to him. Of course, the "mathematical content" of the characterizations is not new, and probably predates category theory.

Comment: @Tyrone As for finite generation: it might be worth adding this fact to the Wikipedia page on [Alexandrov spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology#History), which erroneously dates the term to the 1980s.